# Vue 3 Migration Build with Typescript throwing export 'default' (imported as 'Vue') was not found in 'vue' warning

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I have a vue2 application that I'm attempting to migrate to Vue3 using the Migration Build.  I worked through the steps in the documentation here: https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/migration-build.html and am still getting the following warning

```
export 'default' (imported as 'Vue') was not found in 'vue' (possible exports: BaseTransition, Comment, EffectScope, Fragment, KeepAlive, ReactiveEffect, Static, Suspense, Teleport, Text, Transition, TransitionGroup, VueElement, callWithAsyncErrorHandling, callWithErrorHandling, camelize, capitalize, cloneVNode, compatUtils, compile, computed, createApp, createBlock, createCommentVNode, createElementBlock, createElementVNode, createHydrationRenderer, createPropsRestProxy, createRenderer, createSSRApp, createSlots, createStaticVNode, createTextVNode, createVNode, customRef, defineAsyncComponent, defineComponent, defineCustomElement, defineEmits, defineExpose, defineProps, defineSSRCustomElement, devtools, effect, effectScope, getCurrentInstance, getCurrentScope, getTransitionRawChildren, guardReactiveProps, h, handleError, hydrate, initCustomFormatter, initDirectivesForSSR, inject, isMemoSame, isProxy, isReactive, isReadonly, isRef, isRuntimeOnly, isShallow, isVNode, markRaw, mergeDefaults, mergeProps, nextTick, normalizeClass, normalizeProps, normalizeStyle, onActivated, onBeforeMount, onBeforeUnmount, onBeforeUpdate, onDeactivated, onErrorCaptured, onMounted, onRenderTracked, onRenderTriggered, onScopeDispose, onServerPrefetch, onUnmounted, onUpdated, openBlock, popScopeId, provide, proxyRefs, pushScopeId, queuePostFlushCb, reactive, readonly, ref, registerRuntimeCompiler, render, renderList, renderSlot, resolveComponent, resolveDirective, resolveDynamicComponent, resolveFilter, resolveTransitionHooks, setBlockTracking, setDevtoolsHook, setTransitionHooks, shallowReactive, shallowReadonly, shallowRef, ssrContextKey, ssrUtils, stop, toDisplayString, toHandlerKey, toHandlers, toRaw, toRef, toRefs, transformVNodeArgs, triggerRef, unref, useAttrs, useCssModule, useCssVars, useSSRContext, useSlots, useTransitionState, vModelCheckbox, vModelDynamic, vModelRadio, vModelSelect, vModelText, vShow, version, warn, watch, watchEffect, watchPostEffect, watchSyncEffect, withAsyncContext, withCtx, withDefaults, withDirectives, withKeys, withMemo, withModifiers, withScopeId)
```

I've seen a bunch of SO posts that have similar errors when folks are trying to use vue2 components with vue 3, but my expectation was that I could use Vue.extend in compatibility mode, and that part of this process would be to convert each component individually to use defineComponent and switch compat mode from 2 to 3.

I could see that the workflow would be that there would be some kind of warning, but then when I run the app, I get an error that seems to indicate that extend isn't defined on Vue:

```
App.vue?8f12:10 
        
       Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'extend')
    at ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js!./node_modules/ts-loader/index.js??clonedRuleSet-41.use[1]!./node_modules/vue-loader/dist/index.js??ruleSet[0].use[0]!./src/pages/about/App.vue?vue&type=script&lang=ts (App.vue?8f12:10:16)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19:1)
    at ./src/pages/about/App.vue?vue&type=script&lang=ts (App.vue:23:16)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19:1)
    at ./src/pages/about/App.vue (main.ts:4:16)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19:1)
    at ./src/pages/about/main.ts (TypeStats.ts:100:2)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19:1)
    at startup:4:92
    at __webpack_require__.O (chunk loaded:25:1)
./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js!./node_modules/ts-loader/index.js??clonedRuleSet-41.use[1]!./node_modules/vue-loader/dist/index.js??ruleSet[0].use[0]!./src/pages/about/App.vue?vue&type=script&lang=ts @ App.vue?8f12:10
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:19
./src/pages/about/App.vue?vue&type=script&lang=ts @ App.vue:23
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:19
./src/pages/about/App.vue @ main.ts:4
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:19
./src/pages/about/main.ts @ TypeStats.ts:100
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:19
(anonymous) @ startup:4
__webpack_require__.O @ chunk loaded:25
(anonymous) @ startup:5
(anonymous) @ startup:5
```

I'm using the vue CLI and have set the compiler settings to default to 2 as the documentation suggests:

```
    chainWebpack: (config) => {
        config.resolve.alias.set("vue", "@vue/compat");

        config.module
            .rule("vue")
            .use("vue-loader")
            .tap((options) => {
                return {
                    ...options,
                    compilerOptions: {
                        compatConfig: {
                            MODE: 2,
                        },
                    },
                };
            });
    },
```

And I've created a shims-vue-compat.d.ts file in the root of my source directory:

```
declare module "vue" {
  import { CompatVue } from "@vue/runtime-dom";
  const Vue: CompatVue;
  export default Vue;
  export * from "@vue/runtime-dom";
  const { configureCompat } = Vue;
  export { configureCompat };
}
```

I've tried this with and without the existing shim.vue.d.ts file that I've been running for vue 2:

```
declare module "*.vue" {
  import Vue from "vue";
  export default Vue;
}
```

I've followed all the other steps in the guide to update my package.json, etc.  Am I missing something simple here? Or am I just completely misunderstanding the purpose of the migration build?  Or does it just not support typescript very well?  Do I need to convert all of my Vue.extend to defineComponent in one fell swoop?  Or can I use defineComponent oo something else other than Vue.extend in Vue 2 to make the transition easier?

Is there an example out there of a reasonably straightforward vue 2 typescript app with steps to convert to vue 3 - I've seen a couple of examples of such an app for javascript, but not for typescript.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I was defining aliases in configureWebpack, which appears to be incompatible with chainWebpack.  Moving all of my alias definitions to the chainWebpack section fixed the issue and now I'm seeing a warning for Vue.extend rather than an error.

```
vue.runtime.esm-bundler.js:1598 
        
       [Vue warn]: (deprecation GLOBAL_EXTEND) Vue.extend() has been removed in Vue 3. Use defineComponent() instead.
  Details: https://vuejs.org/api/general.html#definecomponent
```